# boundary cells in cell-vertex finite volume

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary, pde

I have a naive question about boundary conditions in cell vertex (duel control volume) finite volume method. It looks like in cell vertex schemes the boundary cells are always half-cells. For example, with a uniform node spacing of 0.1 between 0 and 1, the first cell is [0,0.05] while the other cells are [0.05,0.15],[0.15,0.25] etc. While the interior cells have computing nodes within them, the half-cells do not. They only have the boundaries.

My question is, after discretization and integration, how to interpret the equation for the half-cells? The integrated equation is for the cell average properties, do we have to assume that the boundary values represent the cell average in the half-cells? Or are there other ways to deal with it? I haven't been able to find answers in books since they rarely deal with this...

Answer (score 0):

Yes but only for flux and source term evaluation because the boundary conditions are pre defined and not needed any kind of time march iteration.

Comment: Use comment section here